# Bootstrap carousel dynamic attribute in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-5, angular16

I am using a Bootstrap 5 carousel that comes with the data-bs-ride="carousel" attribute to autoplay the slides. By using "false" instead of "carousel" it doesn't auto play.

I am trying to swap "carousel" with "false" with buttons so the user can pause the auto play mode:

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- WHEN data-bs-ride="carousel" it auto-plays, when data-bs-ride="false" it stops -->
      <div #carousel id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-pause="false">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div *ngFor="let item of carouselItemsHorizontal" class="carousel-item {{item.activeClass}}" data-bs-interval="3000">
            <img src="{{item.imageSrc}}" class="carouselImage d-flex justify-content-center" alt="{{item.imageAlt}}">
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <button routerLink="about" class="btn">Learn more</button>
              </div>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        
        <div class="carouselPlayPause">
          <svg (click)="playClick()" *ngIf="isPlaying" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-play playPauseColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M10.804 8 5 4.633v6.734zm.792-.696a.802.802 0 0 1 0 1.392l-6.363 3.692C4.713 12.69 4 12.345 4 11.692V4.308c0-.653.713-.998 1.233-.696z"/>
            <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"/>
          </svg>

          <svg (click)="pauseClick()" *ngIf="!isPlaying" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="30" height="30" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-pause playPauseColor" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M6 3.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5m4 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v8a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5"/>
            <path d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"/>
          </svg>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my TypeScript class:

```
export class HomeCarouselComponent {

  dataRide:string = 'carousel';
  isPlaying:boolean = false;

  playClick():void {
    this.dataRide = 'carousel';
    this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
  }

  pauseClick():void {
    this.dataRide = 'false';
    this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
  }

  carouselItemsHorizontal:CarouselItems[] = [
    {
      imageSrc: '../../assets/images/home-images/carousel/main-artboard.png',
      imageAlt: 'Welcome to "Learning Angular" Application banner.',
      activeClass: 'active'
    },
    {
      imageSrc: '../../assets/images/home-images/carousel/sections-artboard.png',
      imageAlt: 'sections',
    },
    {
      imageSrc: '../../assets/images/home-images/carousel/projects-artboard.png',
      imageAlt: 'projects',
    },
  ]
}
```

There's this interface on top as well, for the items shape:

```
interface CarouselItems {
  imageSrc:string;
  imageAlt:string;
  activeClass?:string;
}
```

I tried this `[data-bs-ride]="dataRide"` but gives this error:
Can't bind to 'data-bs-ride' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.ngtsc(-998002)

I also tried this `[attr.data-bs-ride]="dataRide"`, no errors but the buttons don't pause/play the carousel.

Can't use string interpolation either.

Any good suggestions please?

Thank you very much in advance!!!

`[data-bs-ride]="dataRide"` gives error: ngtsc(-998002)

`[attr.data-bs-ride]="dataRide"`, no errors but the buttons don't pause/play the carousel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't work, because you cannot pause/start carousel instance with HTML element attributes.

Instead, control it with JavaScript.

Simply get carousel instance in the component, and then instead of changing data attributes, pause or slide with [`.pause` and `.cycle` methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/carousel/#methods) in your corresponding component methods.

Try this:

```
// get element and instantiate carousel

@ViewChild('carousel') carouselEl!:ElementRef;
carousel!:Carousel;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.carousel = Carousel.getOrCreateInstance(this.carouselEl.nativeElement);
}
```

now simply control instance in your methods:

```
// pause/play

playClick():void {
this.carousel.cycle();
this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
}

pauseClick():void {
this.carousel.pause();
this.isPlaying = !this.isPlaying;
}
```

[**Stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-16-starter-jkgcsf?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I followed exactly what you've done, my code looks exactly like yours but it doesn't work... I wonder what else could happen with this. *edit* I also found this solution again today here, tried it and didn't work..

Comment: well, hard to say.. try starting it manually by adding `this.carousel.cycle();`  in `ngAfterViewInit` right after instantiating it, and remove `data-bs-ride="carousel"` from the template

Comment: I can't believe this worked. Thank you very much bro! Could I start it in ngOnInit instead ?

Comment: Actually, this worked but bugged all my bootstrap dropdown buttons. Any idea on this?

Comment: no, DOM elements and manipulation is available only in ngAfterViewInit, so it won't work in ngOnInit. As there's no dropdown code, I can't tell.. if it's some other component, make sure you import bootstrap in that component, and maybe try instantiating dropdowns manually just like the carousel, in ngAfterViewInit, otherwise, you'll need to include reproducible code, maybe even in a new question, as it's probably different topic

Comment: Ok traynor, Thank you again for your help and I am sorry for bothering you that much! You already solved my problem, thank you!

Comment: no problem. I guess you need to debug your code, try isolating the code that doesn't work, if it's added dynamically, it could be some conflict.., if the code uses many BS components, perhaps you could consider using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), so you wouldn't need to instantiate template elements etc.